# QObject::connect timer with update() function

Tags: c++, qt-creator, connect, qobject

How can I connect `void update(*p_1, *p_2, *p_3, *p_4, *scene)` function with `timer()` using `QObject::connect`?

What I want to accomplish is to update objects to which I've passed the pointers and call `*scene->update()` to refresh screen content.

I've got an update function which looks like this:

```
void update(*p_1, *p_2, *p_3, *p_4, *scene){
    // update functions
    scene->update();
}
```

And in main I've got:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    // creating objects and calculations
    view.show();
    QTimer timer;
    QObject::connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), update(&o_1, ..., &scene));
    timer.start(1000);
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: This is how it's supposed to be done: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-collidingmice-example.html#the-main-function

Answer (score 1):

The signatures of the signal and of the function are not *compatible*. Because if that, according to the documentation, you cannot connect them directly.
Anyway, you can use a lambda to work around the it:

```
QObject::connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), [&](){ update(&o_1, ..., &scene); });
```

Comment: The problem was that timer and update were not part of a class. After creating proper class with both problem was gone.